# Qt Class Naming Convention

Tags: c++, qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the name of my classes begin with ‘Q’ in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921915/should-the-name-of-my-classes-begin-with-q-in-qt)

This is similar the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401851/naming-convention-for-qt-widgets) which asks about variable naming conventions of widgets. My question has to deal with extension qt classes.

Is it customary/recommended to prefix my own widget classes (or any class extended from a Qt class for that matter) with a Q, or should I avoid this? I've seen a few classes from other libraries which do add the Q (e.g. QwtPlot and qextserialport), but I can't tell if it's generally recommended or not.

I would imagine that it's an easy way to tell what classes are intended to be used with the Qt framework, but there is a potential for name clashes with future Qt versions, especially with more common generic widget types. This could be avoided somewhat by using namespaces, but personally I've never been too big a fan of having name clashes even if namespaces provide a clear delineation.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. Thanks Rasmus Faber. Added my vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the documentation where they subclass QThread :

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
 public:
      void run();
};
```

from here : http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qthread.html

They didn't name something like QMyThread, it would create confusion between Qt classes and your classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid "Q" as a prefix.  "Q" is reserved for classes that are a part of the Qt development environment, and if you avoid using "Q" you assure that you'll never accidentally create a class name that conflicts with a Qt environment class.

It's best to pick your own 1-2 letter prefix (**not** beginning with "Q") and stick with it.

(PS: The same goes for several other programming environments.  Programmers on IBM AS/400 are discouraged from using "Q" for the same reason -- OS/400 uses "Q" as its prefix.)

Comment: That sounds so _C-ish_...

Comment: Namespaces are your friend.